# Cloudflare IP Access to the Website DDOS Protection?

Tags: php, security, dns, cloudflare, ddos

I just wonder if Cloudflare is protecting only the domain name accesses ? Lets say I have a website mydomain.com and this domain has a dedicatedIP, 192.168.1.1 if someone uses 192.168.1.1 with the browser it is possible to access to the website. So the DDOS attack as well. In this case can writing a php code will prevent from direct ip access ddos attacks ? Like checking if the entered url is a domain or IP, if it is IP show 403 ?

%99.9 ddos attackers do not use domain name to attack, they first check the dns records of the domain and they attack to the website IP, especially if you have a dedicated IP assigned to the website, even if you hide the mainIP of the website by using Cloudflare nameservers, the mx and email IP dns records are listed again and they are your dedicatedIP where pointed to your website when you call that IP. This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudflare's DDOS protection is only useful if you hide the origin IP - the IP of your server. They have [an article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ddos-prevention-protecting-the-origin/) with tips on this. You'll want to point MX etc. records somewhere else and send mail from a different server, because you're right - it would reveal the IP of the server.

If your host supports it, you can also firewall off your server from any IP address that isn't in Cloudflare's range.

Comment: I have VPS and I have CSF firewall installed. I couldnt understand your suggestion about firewall off, could you please give me some more information about it ?

Comment: @user2228185 A firewall on the instance like CSF won't help. A firewall outside the instance - like Amazon's security groups - could prevent traffic from getting to the server itself.